# pd.replace not behaving as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been using this method to assign characteristics to their respective numbers within a dataframe:

```
usagers = usagers.replace({'actp':{-1:'Non renseigné', 0:'Non renseigné ou sans objet', 1:'Sens véhicule heurtant', 2:'Sens inverse du véhicule', 3:'Traversant', 4:'Masqué', 5:'Jouant – courant', 6:'Avec animal', 9:'Autre', 'A':'Monte/descend du véhicule', 'B':'Inconnue'}})
```

Worked perfectly for all of the data except for this one column...

Anyone have an idea why it wouldn't work on a specific column?
It doesn't produce an error it just runs and does nothing to the values.

Cheers !

Comment: What is dtype of said column?

Comment: The dtype is Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The dtype is Object*

This suggest you have `str`s representing numbers rather than numbers, try chaning keys in your `dict` to `str`s. Consider following example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["1", "2", "3"]})
print(df.x.dtype)  # object
df["x1"] = df.x.replace({1: "A", 2: "B", 3: "C"})
df["x2"] = df.x.replace({"1": "A", "2": "B", "3": "C"})
print(df)
```

output

```
   x x1 x2
0  1  1  A
1  2  2  B
2  3  3  C
```

`"1"` (`str` holding single character) and `1` (`int`) are different, therefore you need correct one in your `dict`.

Comment: Okay, you are right it has to do with the dtype, its the only column in the dataset that has both letters and numbers, which is why i hadn't encounter the problem yet, i put quotes around the numbers and it worked partially, -1 is still not treated but i know what the problem is now. Thank you !

Comment: Ok and just to conclude, in the end i changed letters "A" and "B" to integers "10" and "11", changed the dtype back to int and it works, i couldn't get it to treat -1 as a string and still replace the value for some reason...